# How can i write to the console the same output of detekt even when the build fails due to max issues reached?

Tags: detekt

I am using the detekt plugn and have overwritten the default detekt.yml file

On build failure, only a summary of issues is shown. Detekt analysis result is not written to the console when maxissues has been excceded.

It would be nice to make the build fail while also writing to the console same detekt logs